# How to fix java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.yaml.snakeyaml.Yaml.<init>(Lorg/yaml/snakeyaml/constructor/BaseConstructor?

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-spark, snakeyaml

I have a spark spring-boot application and upgrading spring boot from 1.X to 2.1.5.Now with spring-boot 2.1.15 upgrade , I am getting snakeyaml error in application startup as:

```
ERROR SpringApplication - Application run failed
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.yaml.snakeyaml.Yaml.<init>(Lorg/yaml/snakeyaml/constructor/BaseConstructor;Lorg/yaml/snakeyaml/representer/Representer;Lorg/yaml/snakeyaml/DumperOptions;Lorg/yaml/snakeyaml/LoaderOptions;Lorg/yaml/snakeyaml/resolver/Resolver;)V
        at org.springframework.boot.env.OriginTrackedYamlLoader.createYaml(OriginTrackedYamlLoader.java:71)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.YamlProcessor.process(YamlProcessor.java:162)
        at org.springframework.boot.env.OriginTrackedYamlLoader.load(OriginTrackedYamlLoader.java:76)
        at org.springframework.boot.env.YamlPropertySourceLoader.load(YamlPropertySourceLoader.java:50)
        at org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigFileApplicationListener$Loader.loadDocuments(ConfigFileApplicationListener.java:544)
        at org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigFileApplicationListener$Loader.load(ConfigFileApplicationListener.java:499)
        at org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigFileApplicationListener$Loader.loadForFileExtension(ConfigFileApplicationListener.java:475)
        at org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigFileApplicationListener$Loader.load(ConfigFileApplicationListener.java:445)
        at org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigFileApplicationListener$Loader.lambda$null$6(ConfigFileApplicationListener.java:427)
        at java.lang.Iterable.forEach(Iterable.java:75)
        at org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigFileApplicationListener$Loader.lambda$load$7(ConfigFileApplicationListener.java:427)
        at java.lang.Iterable.forEach(Iterable.java:75)
        at org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigFileApplicationListener$Loader.load(ConfigFileApplicationListener.java:424)
        at org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigFileApplicationListener$Loader.load(ConfigFileApplicationListener.java:323)
        at org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigFileApplicationListener.addPropertySources(ConfigFileApplicationListener.java:204)
        at org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigFileApplicationListener.postProcessEnvironment(ConfigFileApplicationListener.java:188)
        at org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigFileApplicationListener.onApplicationEnvironmentPreparedEvent(ConfigFileApplicationListener.java:178)
        at org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigFileApplicationListener.onApplicationEvent(ConfigFileApplicationListener.java:166)
        at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.doInvokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:172)
        at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.invokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:165)
        at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:139)
        at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:127)
        at org.springframework.boot.context.event.EventPublishingRunListener.environmentPrepared(EventPublishingRunListener.java:76)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.environmentPrepared(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:53)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.prepareEnvironment(SpringApplication.java:342)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:305)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1215)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1204)
        at com.capitalone.customercore.autolink.AutolinkApp.main(AutolinkApp.java:17)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.JavaMainApplication.start(SparkApplication.scala:52)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:845)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:161)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:184)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.doSubmit(SparkSubmit.scala:86)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$$anon$2.doSubmit(SparkSubmit.scala:920)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:929)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
```

I did check the snakeyaml in dependency:tree and see org.yaml:snakeyaml:jar:1.23:compile
My dependency:tree is :

```
com.test.customercore:autolink-utility:jar:0.30-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter:jar:2.1.15.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot:jar:2.1.15.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-autoconfigure:jar:2.1.15.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- javax.annotation:javax.annotation-api:jar:1.3.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-core:jar:5.1.16.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.springframework:spring-jcl:jar:5.1.16.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.yaml:snakeyaml:jar:1.23:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-expression:jar:5.3.17:compile
[INFO] [INFO] |  +- com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-kinesisvideo:jar:1.11.511:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- io.netty:netty-handler:jar:4.1.50.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |     +- io.netty:netty-common:jar:4.1.50.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |     +- io.netty:netty-resolver:jar:4.1.50.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |     +- io.netty:netty-buffer:jar:4.1.50.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |     +- io.netty:netty-transport:jar:4.1.50.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |     \- io.netty:netty-codec:jar:4.1.50.Final:compile
[INFO] |  [INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-cassandra:jar:2.1.15.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring-tx:jar:5.1.16.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.data:spring-data-cassandra:jar:2.1.18.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-context:jar:5.1.16.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.springframework:spring-aop:jar:5.1.16.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:5.1.16.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.data:spring-data-commons:jar:2.1.18.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.datastax.cassandra:cassandra-driver-core:jar:3.6.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.github.jnr:jnr-ffi:jar:2.1.7:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- com.github.jnr:jffi:jar:1.2.16:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- com.github.jnr:jffi:jar:native:1.2.16:runtime
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.ow2.asm:asm:jar:5.0.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.ow2.asm:asm-commons:jar:5.0.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.ow2.asm:asm-analysis:jar:5.0.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.ow2.asm:asm-tree:jar:5.0.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.ow2.asm:asm-util:jar:5.0.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- com.github.jnr:jnr-x86asm:jar:1.0.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- com.github.jnr:jnr-posix:jar:3.0.44:compile
[INFO] |  |     \- com.github.jnr:jnr-constants:jar:0.9.9:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.30:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test:jar:2.1.15.RELEASE:test
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-test:jar:2.1.15.RELEASE:test
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-test-autoconfigure:jar:2.1.15.RELEASE:test
[INFO] |  +- com.jayway.jsonpath:json-path:jar:2.4.0:test
[INFO] |  |  \- net.minidev:json-smart:jar:2.3:compile
[INFO] |  |     \- net.minidev:accessors-smart:jar:1.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- junit:junit:jar:4.12:test
[INFO] |  +- org.assertj:assertj-core:jar:3.11.1:test
[INFO] |  +- org.mockito:mockito-core:jar:2.23.4:test
[INFO] |  |  +- net.bytebuddy:byte-buddy:jar:1.9.16:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- net.bytebuddy:byte-buddy-agent:jar:1.9.16:test
[INFO] |  |  \- org.objenesis:objenesis:jar:2.6:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:jar:1.3:test
[INFO] |  +- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-library:jar:1.3:test
[INFO] |  +- org.skyscreamer:jsonassert:jar:1.5.0:test
[INFO] |  |  \- com.vaadin.external.google:android-json:jar:0.0.20131108.vaadin1:test
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-test:jar:5.1.16.RELEASE:test
[INFO] |  \- org.xmlunit:xmlunit-core:jar:2.6.4:test
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-log4j:jar:1.3.8.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.slf4j:jcl-over-slf4j:jar:1.7.30:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.slf4j:jul-to-slf4j:jar:1.7.30:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.slf4j:slf4j-log4j12:jar:1.7.30:compile
[INFO] +- org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-api:jar:2.17.1:compile
[INFO] +- com.test.api.customers:customers-relations-common:jar:1.1.28-RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- javax.inject:javax.inject:jar:1:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:jar:3.8.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.commons:commons-collections4:jar:4.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.test.chassis.model:chassis-business-model:jar:3.1.1.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.test.chassis:chassis-annotations:jar:3.1.1.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- io.swagger:swagger-annotations:jar:1.5.21:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- javax.xml.bind:jaxb-api:jar:2.3.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- javax.activation:javax.activation-api:jar:1.2.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.jooq:jool-java-8:jar:0.9.13:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.sun.xml.bind:jaxb-core:jar:2.3.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- com.sun.xml.bind:jaxb-impl:jar:2.3.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.test.chassis.engine:chassis-model:jar:3.1.1.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- javax.ws.rs:javax.ws.rs-api:jar:2.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- javax.validation:validation-api:jar:2.0.1.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- javax.el:javax.el-api:jar:3.0.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.glassfish.web:el-impl:jar:2.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat:jackson-dataformat-yaml:jar:2.9.10:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:jar:2.9.10:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.hamcrest:java-hamcrest:jar:2.0.0.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- redis.clients:jedis:jar:2.9.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.apache.commons:commons-pool2:jar:2.6.2:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework.data:spring-data-redis:jar:2.1.18.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |     +- org.springframework.data:spring-data-keyvalue:jar:2.1.18.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |     +- org.springframework:spring-oxm:jar:5.1.16.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |     \- org.springframework:spring-context-support:jar:5.1.16.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.hibernate.validator:hibernate-validator:jar:6.1.5.Final:compile
[INFO] |  +- jakarta.validation:jakarta.validation-api:jar:2.0.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.jboss.logging:jboss-logging:jar:3.3.3.Final:compile
[INFO] |  \- com.fasterxml:classmate:jar:1.4.0:compile
[INFO] +- org.apache.spark:spark-sql_2.11:jar:2.4.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.univocity:univocity-parsers:jar:2.7.3:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.spark:spark-sketch_2.11:jar:2.4.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.spark:spark-catalyst_2.11:jar:2.4.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.scala-lang.modules:scala-parser-combinators_2.11:jar:1.1.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.codehaus.janino:janino:jar:3.0.16:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.codehaus.janino:commons-compiler:jar:3.0.16:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.antlr:antlr4-runtime:jar:4.7:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.spark:spark-tags_2.11:jar:2.4.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.orc:orc-core:jar:nohive:1.5.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.orc:orc-shims:jar:1.5.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- io.airlift:aircompressor:jar:0.10:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.orc:orc-mapreduce:jar:nohive:1.5.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.parquet:parquet-column:jar:1.10.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.parquet:parquet-common:jar:1.10.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.apache.parquet:parquet-encoding:jar:1.10.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.parquet:parquet-hadoop:jar:1.10.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.parquet:parquet-format:jar:2.4.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.parquet:parquet-jackson:jar:1.10.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-core-asl:jar:1.9.13:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.arrow:arrow-vector:jar:0.10.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.arrow:arrow-format:jar:0.10.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.arrow:arrow-memory:jar:0.10.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.carrotsearch:hppc:jar:0.7.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- com.vlkan:flatbuffers:jar:1.2.0-3f79e055:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.xbean:xbean-asm6-shaded:jar:4.8:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.spark-project.spark:unused:jar:1.0.0:compile
[INFO] +- org.apache.spark:spark-core_2.11:jar:2.4.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.thoughtworks.paranamer:paranamer:jar:2.8:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.avro:avro:jar:1.8.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.tukaani:xz:jar:1.5:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.avro:avro-mapred:jar:hadoop2:1.8.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.apache.avro:avro-ipc:jar:1.8.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.twitter:chill_2.11:jar:0.9.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- com.esotericsoftware:kryo-shaded:jar:4.0.2:compile
[INFO] |  |     \- com.esotericsoftware:minlog:jar:1.3.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.twitter:chill-java:jar:0.9.3:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.spark:spark-launcher_2.11:jar:2.4.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.spark:spark-kvstore_2.11:jar:2.4.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.spark:spark-network-shuffle_2.11:jar:2.4.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.spark:spark-unsafe_2.11:jar:2.4.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- javax.activation:activation:jar:1.1.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.curator:curator-recipes:jar:2.6.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.apache.curator:curator-framework:jar:2.6.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.zookeeper:zookeeper:jar:3.4.6:compile
[INFO] |  +- javax.servlet:javax.servlet-api:jar:4.0.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.commons:commons-math3:jar:3.4.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:jar:1.3.9:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.ning:compress-lzf:jar:1.0.3:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.xerial.snappy:snappy-java:jar:1.1.7.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.lz4:lz4-java:jar:1.4.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.github.luben:zstd-jni:jar:1.3.2-2:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.roaringbitmap:RoaringBitmap:jar:0.5.11:compile
[INFO] |  +- commons-net:commons-net:jar:3.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.scala-lang:scala-library:jar:2.11.12:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.json4s:json4s-jackson_2.11:jar:3.5.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.json4s:json4s-core_2.11:jar:3.5.3:compile
[INFO] |  |     +- org.json4s:json4s-ast_2.11:jar:3.5.3:compile
[INFO] |  |     +- org.json4s:json4s-scalap_2.11:jar:3.5.3:compile
[INFO] |  |     \- org.scala-lang.modules:scala-xml_2.11:jar:1.0.6:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.glassfish.jersey.core:jersey-client:jar:2.27:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.glassfish.hk2.external:javax.inject:jar:2.5.0-b42:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.glassfish.jersey.core:jersey-common:jar:2.27:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.glassfish.hk2:osgi-resource-locator:jar:1.0.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.glassfish.jersey.core:jersey-server:jar:2.27:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.glassfish.jersey.media:jersey-media-jaxb:jar:2.27:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.glassfish.jersey.containers:jersey-container-servlet:jar:2.27:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.glassfish.jersey.containers:jersey-container-servlet-core:jar:2.27:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.clearspring.analytics:stream:jar:2.7.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- io.dropwizard.metrics:metrics-core:jar:3.2.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- io.dropwizard.metrics:metrics-jvm:jar:4.0.7:compile
[INFO] |  +- io.dropwizard.metrics:metrics-json:jar:4.0.7:compile
[INFO] |  +- io.dropwizard.metrics:metrics-graphite:jar:4.0.7:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- com.rabbitmq:amqp-client:jar:5.4.3:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:jar:2.9.10.4:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-scala_2.11:jar:2.9.10:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-paranamer:jar:2.9.10:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.ivy:ivy:jar:2.4.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- oro:oro:jar:2.0.8:compile
[INFO] |  +- net.razorvine:pyrolite:jar:4.13:compile
[INFO] |  +- net.sf.py4j:py4j:jar:0.10.7:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.apache.commons:commons-crypto:jar:1.0.0:compile
[INFO] +- org.apache.spark:spark-network-common_2.11:jar:2.4.6:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.fusesource.leveldbjni:leveldbjni-all:jar:1.8:compile
[INFO] |  \- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:jar:2.9.10:compile
[INFO] +- commons-codec:commons-codec:jar:1.13:compile
[INFO] +- org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-1.2-api:jar:2.17.1:compile
[INFO] +- commons-lang:commons-lang:jar:2.6:compile
[INFO] +- com.datastax.spark:spark-cassandra-connector-unshaded_2.11:jar:2.4.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.joda:joda-convert:jar:1.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- joda-time:joda-time:jar:2.10.6:compile
[INFO] |  +- io.netty:netty-all:jar:4.1.50.Final:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.twitter:jsr166e:jar:1.1.0:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.scala-lang:scala-reflect:jar:2.11.12:compile
[INFO] +- org.cassandraunit:cassandra-unit:jar:3.1.1.0:test
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.cassandra:cassandra-all:jar:3.9:test
[INFO] |  |  +- net.jpountz.lz4:lz4:jar:1.3.0:test
[INFO] |  |  +- commons-cli:commons-cli:jar:1.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.googlecode.concurrentlinkedhashmap:concurrentlinkedhashmap-lru:jar:1.4:test
[INFO] |  |  +- org.antlr:antlr:jar:3.5.2:test
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.antlr:ST4:jar:4.0.8:test
[INFO] |  |  +- org.antlr:antlr-runtime:jar:3.5.2:test
[INFO] |  |  +- org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-mapper-asl:jar:1.9.2:test
[INFO] |  |  +- com.googlecode.json-simple:json-simple:jar:1.1:test
[INFO] |  |  +- com.boundary:high-scale-lib:jar:1.0.6:test
[INFO] |  |  +- org.mindrot:jbcrypt:jar:0.3m:test
[INFO] |  |  +- com.addthis.metrics:reporter-config3:jar:3.0.0:test
[INFO] |  |  |  \- com.addthis.metrics:reporter-config-base:jar:3.0.0:test
[INFO] |  |  +- com.thinkaurelius.thrift:thrift-server:jar:0.3.7:test
[INFO] |  |  |  \- com.lmax:disruptor:jar:3.0.1:test
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.thrift:libthrift:jar:0.9.2:test
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.cassandra:cassandra-thrift:jar:3.9:test
[INFO] |  |  |  +- de.jflex:jflex:jar:1.6.0:test
[INFO] |  |  |  |  \- org.apache.ant:ant:jar:1.7.0:test
[INFO] |  |  |  |     \- org.apache.ant:ant-launcher:jar:1.7.0:test
[INFO] |  |  |  +- net.mintern:primitive:jar:1.0:test
[INFO] |  |  |  +- com.github.rholder:snowball-stemmer:jar:1.3.0.581.1:test
[INFO] |  |  |  \- com.googlecode.concurrent-trees:concurrent-trees:jar:2.4.0:test
[INFO] |  |  +- net.java.dev.jna:jna:jar:4.5.2:test
[INFO] |  |  +- com.github.jbellis:jamm:jar:0.3.0:test
[INFO] |  |  +- org.fusesource:sigar:jar:1.6.4:test
[INFO] |  |  +- org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler:ecj:jar:4.4.2:test
[INFO] |  |  +- org.caffinitas.ohc:ohc-core:jar:0.4.3:test
[INFO] |  |  \- com.github.ben-manes.caffeine:caffeine:jar:2.6.2:test
[INFO] |  \- com.google.guava:guava:jar:18.0:compile
[INFO] +- io.netty:netty:jar:3.10.6.Final:compile
[INFO] +- org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-client:jar:3.3.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-common:jar:3.3.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.hadoop.thirdparty:hadoop-shaded-protobuf_3_7:jar:1.1.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.hadoop.thirdparty:hadoop-shaded-guava:jar:1.1.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:jar:4.5.12:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:jar:4.4.13:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- commons-io:commons-io:jar:2.8.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- commons-collections:commons-collections:jar:3.2.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- jakarta.activation:jakarta.activation-api:jar:1.2.1:runtime
[INFO] |  |  +- javax.servlet.jsp:jsp-api:jar:2.1:runtime
[INFO] |  |  +- com.sun.jersey:jersey-servlet:jar:1.19:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- commons-beanutils:commons-beanutils:jar:1.9.4:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.commons:commons-configuration2:jar:2.1.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.commons:commons-text:jar:1.4:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.google.re2j:re2j:jar:1.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.google.protobuf:protobuf-java:jar:2.5.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.google.code.gson:gson:jar:2.8.6:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-auth:jar:3.3.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- com.nimbusds:nimbus-jose-jwt:jar:9.8.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |  \- com.github.stephenc.jcip:jcip-annotations:jar:1.0-1:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.apache.kerby:kerb-simplekdc:jar:1.0.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  |     +- org.apache.kerby:kerb-client:jar:1.0.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  |     |  +- org.apache.kerby:kerby-config:jar:1.0.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  |     |  +- org.apache.kerby:kerb-common:jar:1.0.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  |     |  |  \- org.apache.kerby:kerb-crypto:jar:1.0.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  |     |  +- org.apache.kerby:kerb-util:jar:1.0.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  |     |  \- org.apache.kerby:token-provider:jar:1.0.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  |     \- org.apache.kerby:kerb-admin:jar:1.0.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  |        +- org.apache.kerby:kerb-server:jar:1.0.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  |        |  \- org.apache.kerby:kerb-identity:jar:1.0.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  |        \- org.apache.kerby:kerby-xdr:jar:1.0.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.curator:curator-client:jar:4.2.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.commons:commons-compress:jar:1.21:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.kerby:kerb-core:jar:1.0.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.apache.kerby:kerby-pkix:jar:1.0.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  |     +- org.apache.kerby:kerby-asn1:jar:1.0.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  |     \- org.apache.kerby:kerby-util:jar:1.0.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.codehaus.woodstox:stax2-api:jar:4.2.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.fasterxml.woodstox:woodstox-core:jar:5.0.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- dnsjava:dnsjava:jar:2.1.7:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-hdfs-client:jar:3.3.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:jar:2.7.5:compile
[INFO] |  |     \- com.squareup.okio:okio:jar:1.6.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-yarn-api:jar:3.3.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-yarn-client:jar:3.3.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.jline:jline:jar:3.9.0:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-annotations:jar:3.3.2:compile
[INFO] \- commons-configuration:commons-configuration:jar:1.10:compile
[INFO]    \- commons-logging:commons-logging:jar:1.1.1:compile
[INFO] --------------------------------------------------------------------
```

how do I resolve snakeyaml error?

Answer (score 0):

So, you had been using Snakeyaml with an earlier Spring Boot version, but with a newer Spring Boot version, Snakeyaml stopped working. This very much seems to be a version incompatibility issue.

Here: https://search.maven.org/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter/2.1.15.RELEASE/jar

we can see this structure:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd" xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starters</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.15.RELEASE</version>
  </parent>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
  <version>2.1.15.RELEASE</version>
  <name>Spring Boot Starter</name>
  <description>Core starter, including auto-configuration support, logging and YAML</description>
  <url>https://projects.spring.io/spring-boot/#/spring-boot-parent/spring-boot-starters/spring-boot-starter</url>
  <organization>
    <name>Pivotal Software, Inc.</name>
    <url>https://spring.io</url>
  </organization>
  <licenses>
    <license>
      <name>Apache License, Version 2.0</name>
      <url>https://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0</url>
    </license>
  </licenses>
  <developers>
    <developer>
      <name>Pivotal</name>
      <email>info@pivotal.io</email>
      <organization>Pivotal Software, Inc.</organization>
      <organizationUrl>https://www.spring.io</organizationUrl>
    </developer>
  </developers>
  <scm>
    <connection>scm:git:git://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot.git</connection>
    <developerConnection>scm:git:ssh://git@github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot.git</developerConnection>
    <url>https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot</url>
  </scm>
  <issueManagement>
    <system>Github</system>
    <url>https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues</url>
  </issueManagement>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot</artifactId>
      <version>2.1.15.RELEASE</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-autoconfigure</artifactId>
      <version>2.1.15.RELEASE</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
      <version>2.1.15.RELEASE</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>javax.annotation</groupId>
      <artifactId>javax.annotation-api</artifactId>
      <version>1.3.2</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
      <version>5.1.16.RELEASE</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.yaml</groupId>
      <artifactId>snakeyaml</artifactId>
      <version>1.23</version>
      <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

where the interesting part from our perspective is:

```
      <artifactId>snakeyaml</artifactId>
      <version>1.23</version>
```

so, you will likely need to ensure that your Snakeyaml version is **1.23**.

Comment: even I have the 1.23 , still the error is same.

Answer (score 0):

Excluding snakeyaml as a transitive depdendency from spring-boot-starter-web and spring-boot-starter-test

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.yaml</groupId>
                <artifactId>snakeyaml</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
```

and added with scope = runtime.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.yaml</groupId>
        <artifactId>snakeyaml</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>
```

Comment: I encountered a similar error with Quarkus, but was able to resolve it by adding the runtime scope dependency for snakeyaml. This solution won't work if the dependency is added at the end of the <dependencies> section.